# Consuming different mediatype for root path of webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I have following code

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayPlainTextHello(@Context UriInfo wsContext) 
    {
        return "hello from xml";
    }
}
```

This will result in a path `http://localhost:8080/WSTest/rest/hello`. Now i want to have 2 different method so that when a user calls `http://localhost:8080/WSTest/rest/hello.xml` it goes to XML method and when it calls `http://localhost:8080/WSTest/rest/hello.json` it goes to JSON method. With current implementation, if i add `.xml` or `.json` at the end of the path, the server returns `not found` error.

**EDIT**
here is my web.xml. Please note that if add a subpath lets say `@Path("{name}.xml")` which means the `web.xml` is fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>WSTest</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.personal.ws.test</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

P.S:
I can't change the path, we want to keep the root path as `http://localhost:8080/WSTest/rest/hello` it is.

Comment: You exactly ansewered your question in this description : `@Path("{name}.xml")`. It did not work for me otherwise like you.

Comment: If you want it to work use `/` like `/json` otherwise use the same thing that you mentioned.

Comment: i know but the original question is, I want to work it as hello.xml not hello/xml

Comment: The answer is it's not possible otherwise you use `@Path("{name}.xml")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@Path` annotations to your methods:

```
@Path("/rest")
public class Hello {

    @Path("/hello.xml")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXmlHello(@Context UriInfo wsContext) {
        return "hello from xml";
    }

    @Path("/hello.json")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String sayJsonHello(@Context UriInfo wsContext) {
        return "hello from json";
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and ran it, it didn't work. opening the url `http://localhost:8080/WSTest/rest/hello.json` or `http://localhost:8080/WSTest/rest/hello.xml` results in 404.

Comment: I've updated my answer in light of the new information in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as @Ali suggested by having the client request the proper encoding.

You can augment this functionality by adding extension support. This way web browsers and clients that can't set the response format they want (for whatever reason) can still switch media types. You can do this by extending `PackagesResourceConfig` like:

```java
public class CommonResourceConfig extends PackagesResourceConfig {

  public CommonResourceConfig(Map<String, Object> props) {
    super(props);
  }

  public CommonResourceConfig(String... packages) {
    super(packages);
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, MediaType> getMediaTypeMappings() {
    Map<String, MediaType> map = new HashMap<String, MediaType>();
    map.put("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
    map.put("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    return map;
  }
}
```

and then tell Jersey to look for this configuration by setting the `javax.ws.rs.Application` property to the fully qualified name of that class (in your web.xml unless you use some DI mechanism). Also you'll need to update the @Produces annotation on your method to support all the media types you want to handle. This way you don't have to duplicate functionality between methods just to change the media type of the service.

**EDIT:** 
Hello.java is exactly as you have it and the CommonResourceConfig is as above (all in `src/main/java/com/personal/ws/test/`). Here's the rest of my configuration that works (locally, at least):

`pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>jerseyTest</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.3.v20111011</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guice</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
    <display-name>WSTest</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.personal.ws.test</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.personal.ws.test.CommonResourceConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Run a `mvn jetty:run` and then wget or use a browser for `http://localhost:8080/rest/hello.json` and `http://localhost:8080/rest/hello.xml`. I get the right result... maybe just some small configuration issue?

Comment: Nops, its not working. Here is the test which i executed and it is still returning 404

`Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET http://localhost:8080/WsTest/rest/hello returned a response status of 404 Not Found
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:686)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
 at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:507)
 at WsCallee.main(WsCallee.java:18)`

Comment: What does your `web.xml` look like?

Comment: And you tried adding: `<init-param>
   <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
   <param-value>org.example.CommonResourceConfig</param-value>
  </init-param>` (where org.example.CommonResourceConfig is the fully qualified location of your class) below your existing init-param?

Comment: Yup, IE gave me 405 response i.e. **Method not allowed**. However, the little java code which is calling that webservice (as written by Ali) is giving me 404

Comment: Yup, IE and Java code (by Ali) is giving me 405 response i.e. **Method not allowed**.

Comment: Very odd - I'll update my answer with my exact code. It's working for me when I run in Jetty...